# Querying multiple categories in the WP loop if one of the category IDs is dynamically obtained

Tags: posts, loop

I don't know exactly where this is going wrong, but what I figure is happening is that the category I am dynamically obtaining based not the BuddyPress Group slug (post categories have matching names) is being converted to an integer instead of a string and as such isn't looping them in.

```
function chapter_posts() {
    //Get Group Slug
    $chapterSlug    = bp_get_current_group_slug();

    $chapterCatID   = get_cat_id( $chapterSlug );

    //Get posts
    global $post;

    $args = array(
        'cat'           =>  '$chapterCatID,15',
        'posts_per_page'    =>  5
        );
    $posts = get_posts( $args ); ?>

<div class="group_post_start">
    <ul>
        <?php
        foreach( $posts as $post ): setup_postdata($post);
        ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>"><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a>
            <div class="group_post_display">
                <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>" class="button">Read More</a></p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <?php
        endforeach;
        wp_reset_postdata(); // reset the query ?>
    </ul>
</div><!--.group_post_start-->
<div class="group_post_end">
    <a href="<?php echo get_site_url();?>/blog/category/mompreneurs/<?php echo $postCategory; ?>/" class="button">More</a>
</div><!--.group_post_end-->

<?php
}
add_action( 'bp_before_group_home_content', 'chapter_posts', 50);
```

On every BuddyPress group page I want to display a blend of both the primary post category (ID = 15) and the category whose slug matches the slug of the BP group.

To test this out what I do is find a place to basically echo out what the $chapterCatID ends up as and when I do this:

```
<?php echo $chapterCatID; ?>
```

...it always ends up as 0, which, according to the codex, is a failure.  So what I need to know is how do I get the result of the get_cat_id() function to remain as a string?

Comment: the function is `get_cat_ID`, capital ID. also, variables aren't expanded inside single quotes, you are passing literally `$chapterCatID`, not the value of that variable.

Comment: Thanks Milo... ...I had actually just added the single quotes in a furious attempt to get it to work.  My original attempts passed the variable without the single quotes.

I can't believe I messed up the 'get_cat_ID'.  *slaps forehead*

Although, I'm pretty sure that even with that it still didn't work... ...it was originally an uppercase ID.

Answer (score 0):

So, I think I've got it figured out... ...get_cat_ID didn't seem to be the correct function.  I swapped it out with *get_category_by_slug* and that eventually got it up and running.

```
//LINK IN BLOG POSTS THAT MATCH CHAPTER SLUG
function chapter_posts() {
    //Get Group Slug
    $postCategory   = bp_get_current_group_slug();

    //Get posts
    global $post;

    $chapterCatID   = get_category_by_slug($postCategory)->term_id;

    $args = array(
        'cat'           =>  ''. $chapterCatID . ',15',
        'posts_per_page'    =>  4
        );
    $posts = get_posts( $args ); ?>

<div class="group_post_start">
    <ul>
        <?php
        foreach( $posts as $post ): setup_postdata($post);
        ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>"><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a>
            <div class="group_post_display">
                <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>" class="button">Read More</a></p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <?php
        endforeach;
        wp_reset_postdata(); // reset the query ?>
    </ul>
</div><!--.group_post_start-->
<div class="group_post_end">
    <a href="<?php echo get_site_url();?>/blog/category/mompreneurs/<?php echo $postCategory; ?>/" class="button">More</a>
</div><!--.group_post_end-->

<?php
}
add_action( 'bp_before_group_home_content', 'chapter_posts', 50);
```